# Nginx stopped and failed to restart - open() “/run/nginx.pid” failed

Tags: nginx, django, gunicorn, supervisord, certbot

I am running my django apis, deployed on Ubuntu 18, on Nginx and running via Supervisor.

I am using Certbot for SSL certs and this is the only web service running on this webserver. No other websites are deployed here.

The APIs went down today and nginx stopped working. I am not able to recreate why this happened, it had to be manually restarted.

I have faced this once before and had similar error messages in the logs.

Following are the nginx error logs.

```
2021/01/09 15:55:39 [crit] 9453#9453: *1331764 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:1420918C:SSL routines:tls_early_post_process_client_hello:version too low) while SSL handshaking, client: <CLIENT IP ADDRESS>, server: 0.0.0.0:443
2021/01/09 20:39:55 [error] 9453#9453: *1337050 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream, client: <CLIENT IP ADDRESS>, server: , request: "PUT /api/v1/APIURL/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v1/APIURL", host: "<URL>", referrer: "<URL>"
2021/01/09 20:40:12 [error] 9453#9453: *1337057 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream, client: <CLIENT IP ADDRESS>, server: , request: "PUT /api/v1/APIURL/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v1/APIURL", host: "<URL>", referrer: "<URL>"
2021/01/09 20:41:02 [error] 9453#9453: *1337064 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading upstream, client:<CLIENT IP ADDRESS>, server: , request: "PUT /api/v1/URL/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/api/v1/URL/", host: "URL", referrer: "URL"
2021/01/10 03:51:29 [notice] 32527#32527: signal process started
2021/01/10 03:51:29 [error] 32527#32527: open() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
2021/01/10 03:51:34 [notice] 32533#32533: signal process started
2021/01/10 03:51:36 [notice] 32536#32536: signal process started
2021/01/10 03:51:38 [emerg] 32583#32583: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/01/10 03:51:38 [emerg] 32583#32583: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/01/10 03:51:38 [emerg] 32583#32583: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/01/10 03:51:38 [emerg] 32583#32583: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/01/10 03:51:38 [emerg] 32583#32583: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/01/10 03:51:38 [emerg] 32583#32583: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/01/10 03:51:38 [emerg] 32583#32583: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/01/10 03:51:38 [emerg] 32583#32583: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/01/10 03:51:38 [emerg] 32583#32583: bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/01/10 03:51:38 [emerg] 32583#32583: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
2021/01/10 03:51:38 [emerg] 32583#32583: still could not bind()
2021/01/10 03:51:40 [alert] 32534#32534: *6 open socket #10 left in connection 4
2021/01/10 03:51:40 [alert] 32534#32534: aborting
2021/01/10 03:51:40 [alert] 32529#32529: unlink() "/run/nginx.pid" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

Following is my nginx, start script, and supervisor files.

Supervisor:

```
   [program:<PROGRAM NAME>]
    command = /home/ubuntu/start_scripts/script.sh
    directory = /home/ubuntu/LOCATION
    user = ubuntu
    stdout_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/api.log
    stderr_logfile = /var/log/supervisor/api_error.log
    redirect_stderr = true
    stopasgroup=true
    killasgroup=true
```

Start script:

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="API"                                  # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=""           # Django project directory
SOCKFILE="<DJANGO APP>/run/gunicorn.sock"  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER="ubuntu"                                      # the user to run as
GROUP="ubuntu"                                  # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS="2"                                    # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
TIMEOUT=180
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE="config.settings.production"             # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE="config.wsgi"                   # WSGI module name
VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME="project-env"

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"
export HOME="/home/ubuntu"
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs

# Activate the virtual environment
cd $DJANGODIR
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
workon $VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
#echo $PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH
#echo $PYTHONPATH
#export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.4
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON="/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/$VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME/bin/python"

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

exec "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/$VIRTUAL_ENV_NAME/bin/gunicorn" ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind="localhost":"8081" \
  --log-level="debug" \
  --timeout=$TIMEOUT
```

Ngnix sites available:

```
server {
    root <DJANGO PROJECT URL>;
    client_max_body_size 500M;
   
    
    location /healthcheck {
      return 200;
    }

    location /static/ {
      alias /home/ubuntu/apps/<DJANGO>/static/;
    }


    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8081;
        #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout 180s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 180s;
        proxy_set_header Connection '';
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        chunked_transfer_encoding off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_cache off;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<URL>/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<URL>/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = <URL>) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name <URL-without-http>;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Output for `sudo netstat -nltup | grep -e 80 -e 443`

```
tcp        0   0 127.0.0.1:8081   0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      1079/python
tcp        0   0 0.0.0.0:443      0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      -
tcp        0   0 0.0.0.0:80       0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN      -
```

Please help!

Edits:
Upon further inspection of the logs, I can see the last request processed before it went down was the below one.

```
"GET /.well-known/acme-challenge/G8e_pHx5B6fm9xuLzrjJmCvOnPbz8NhJFoWgt4dHGsg HTTP/1.1" 200 87 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Let's Encrypt validation server; +https://www.letsencrypt.org)"
```

It looks like something from certbot was triggered post this request and that's when the server failed to start.

Comment: It is saying in errors that bind address already in use. (port 80, 443). Have you cross checked if any service occupying these ports.?

Comment: use command to check : netstat -nltup | grep -e 80 -e 443

Comment: Yes, but there was no other service running. When it was down, it was restarted, so don't have the output of the command then. Currently it only shows this

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1079/python         
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -                   
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -

Comment: Check nginx and system logs of that time frame. There must be some clue in the logs. Don't forget to check error logs as well

Comment: Please add the output of `netstat` into the question so that it is properly formatted. It seems there is something using port 80.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen edited!

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I am sure no other service was run by anyone on that port. The weird thing is it just randomly went down, with above logs.

Comment: Please use `sudo netstat -nltup | grep -e 80 -e 443` to see what software is listening to those ports.

Comment: Updated. Also on further inspection of logs, I found that the server went down after this particular request was processed. Please refer to my edits.